# MpAndroidChart obtain zero value line in barchart

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart for a barchart.
Actually i have this situation:
[image]

For the first 2 value i have 0.0 but i want the blue line to be drawn also for the zero value, like this:
[image]

I obtained this result by getting a very low percentage of the max value but i want to display the line in 0.0 and not showing 0.5.
If the value is 0.0 i don't want to change it to show the line. Is there a way? Some ideas?

This is the settings of my barchart:

```
   YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
  leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
    barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).setEnabled(true);
 barChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).setDrawGridLines(false);
    barChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).setDrawLabels(false);
    barChart.getAxis(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT).setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could fix this by writing a custom [`IValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface) that would floor y-values less than a given amount down to zero. Then the y-values would render at `0.5f` but be labeled `0.0`.

Here is a very rough example adapted from the `DefaultValueFormatter` in the project:

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FlooringValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter
{

    protected DecimalFormat mFormat;

    protected int mDecimalDigits;
    protected float mMinimum;

    public FlooringValueFormatter(int digits, float minimum) {
        setup(digits);
        this.mMinimum = minimum;
    }

    public void setup(int digits) {

        this.mDecimalDigits = digits;

        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                b.append(".");
            b.append("0");
        }

        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0" + b.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        if (value < mMinimum) {
            return mFormat.format(0);
        }

        return mFormat.format(value);
    }

    public int getDecimalDigits() {
        return mDecimalDigits;
    }
}
```

Consume it like this:

```
barData.setValueFormatter(new FlooringValueFormatter(2, 0.5f));
```